Opera: logging in using Google does not offer a reset password
Fresh 24.04. Firefox asks for mail and then there is a message sent to my phone that lets me log in. So no need for a password. (FF 24.04 version does not let me download anything so time to review my browser choice... Opera it is my 1st one to try; what I just also noticed it does not let me add images from outside of ./snap/firefox/current/)
Opera asks for a password but claims there is a clickable link but it is plain text. It should do 2fa and send a confirmation message.

